# redirect to HTTPS if not HTTPS by .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I want to redirect user to HTTPS (**https://www.example.com**)
if they come with
 - example.com
 - www.example.com
 - http://example.com
 - http://www.example.com

I already used this code on .htaccess. but it's not working for, www.example.com, http://www.example.com

```
# BEGIN SSL Redirect
RewriteEngine on
# force ssl
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^calbel\.com
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
# END SSL Redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

there are dozens of ways, try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This page isn’t working
www.example.com redirected you too many times.

Comment: then you have other rules

Answer (score 0):

if it is not mandatory to use .htaccess why not just use:

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

Comment: because it makes so much more sense to do it at the web server level.

Comment: thanks,it depends on the traffic of the website though.

Comment: what "depends on the traffic of the website"? and how about all the non php resources that wont be served vis ssl this way?

Comment: Sorry, I need to do it with . htaccess
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same issue use below code for force redirect to https

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

if not

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This page isn’t working
example.com redirected you too many times.

Comment: change that `www.example.com`  to your domain

Comment: what is your actual domain name which you are trying for\

Comment: Its working and showing me secure green mark for [ https://www.calbel.com/ ]. It is unable to find the `Htest`

Comment: calbel.com is live site. I'm testing on calbel.com/Htest. on calbel.com when you will go with www.calbel.com then it must should redirect to https://www.calbel.com bt not working anymore

Comment: you cannot test it by creating the folder you need to create an sub domain and then check the https redirect

Comment: I just try on live, bt same problem :(

Comment: But I can see it on my its redirecting to https. Clean your cache or try with different browser

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```